# How do I loop a nested array in laravel to get an array based on conditions of key values from that array

Tags: php, laravel, multidimensional-array

I want to get only the arrays where the option is not null
When i get the arrays back successfully,
i also want to add it to a database, but most importantly i want to get the arrays back

```
array:3 [
  0 => array:5 [
    "id" => 6
    "option" => "True"
    "is_correct" => true
    "label" => "True"
    "opid" => 1
  ]
  1 => array:5 [
    "id" => 7
    "option" => "False"
    "is_correct" => false
    "label" => "False"
    "opid" => 1
  ]
  2 => array:5 [
    "id" => 8
    "option" => null
    "is_correct" => false
    "label" => "Theory"
    "opid" => 5
  ]
]
```

**EXPECTED RESULT**

```
array:3 [
      0 => array:5 [
        "id" => 6
        "option" => "True"
        "is_correct" => true
        "label" => "True"
        "opid" => 1
      ]
      1 => array:5 [
        "id" => 7
        "option" => "False"
        "is_correct" => false
        "label" => "False"
        "opid" => 1
      ]
    ]
```

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**

```
foreach($request->option as $option) {
   if($option["option"] == null){
       dd($option)
    }
}
```

i only get the first value from the array.. it appears like my if condition is not working as well

i'll be in the comments thank you

Comment: What have you tried though?

Comment: can you add what you have tried so some one can help you to solve

Comment: Okay i'll do that

Comment: i have added what i have tried John Lobo and user3532758

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose if your `$request->option` contain array then

```
$filtered = collect($request->option)->whereNotNull('option')->all()->toArray();
```

Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-wherenotnull

Answer (score 0):

Try `except` method,

Read documentation -
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-collections#method-contains

Comment: This isn't what i'm looking for

Comment: I am sorry my answer didn't work for you, would you elaborate a little on what you want then??